# HTML/JS - How should I approach ensuring a user has finished the authentication process before allowing them to move on?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am in the process of building a web application that will allow users to generate a Spotify playlists of songs they've tweeted. This involves using both the Spotify API (via the wrapper spotipy) and the Twitter API (via the wrapper Twython). So far, I have been able to get the implicit grant/authorization code flow working for both APIS but am struggling to figure out what is the best way to approach confirming the user on the web application has finished authorizing their Twitter and Spotify accounts before pressing a button that will generate the playlist.

I'm a little stuck because it seems you can't disable buttons with an href attribute. Also, I tried creating JavaScript functions that enable the "Build Playlist" button but that isn't working either. Below is the HTML for the webpage the user would be on when authenticating their accounts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Your Twitter Playlist </title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Authentication</h1>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

</body>

   <button type="button" id="home"> 
       <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/"> Home </a> 
   </button>

   <button type="button" id="auth_twitter" data-twit-clickToggle="false" onclick=clickToggleTwitter()>
       <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/twitter"> Twitter </a>  
    </button>

   <button type="button" id="auth_spotify" data-spot-clickToggle="false" onclick=clickToggleSpotify()> 
       <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/spotify"> Spotify </a> 
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="build_playlist" disabled="disabled" onclick=enableBuildButton()>
        Create Playlist! 
    </button>

    <!-- ********************* SCRIPTS ************************** -->

    <!--    Enable Build Playlist Button -->
    <script>
        function enableBuildButton() {

            var spotify_toggle = document.getElementById("auth_spotify").getAttribute("data-spot-clickToggle");

            var twitter_toggle = document.getElementById("auth_twitter").getAttribute("data-twit-clickToggle");


            if spotify_toggle and twitter_toggle == "true": 

                document.getElementById("build_playlist").disabled = false; 
        }
    </script>

    <!--    Twitter Button Toggle -->
    <script>
        function clickToggleTwitter() { 
            document.getElementById("auth_twitter").setAttribute("data-twit-clickToggle") = "true";     

        }
    </script>

    <!--    Spotify Button Toggle -->
     <script>
        function clickToggleSpotify() { 
            document.getElementById("auth_spotify").setAttribute("data-spot-clickToggle") = "true";    

        }
    </script>


</html>
```

I guess my question is how should approach solving this problem? I have no experience with web development so any helpful resources would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I know this question is kind of all over the place! Please let me know if seeing code snippets of the actual app itself written in Python/Flask would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `enableBuildButton()` was not working because there were syntax errors. (JavaScript does not understand Python syntax!)

It works when changed like this:

```
function enableBuildButton() {
    var spotify_toggle = document.getElementById("auth_spotify").getAttribute("data-spot-clickToggle");
    var twitter_toggle = document.getElementById("auth_twitter").getAttribute("data-twit-clickToggle");

    // Python syntax changed to JS
    if (spotify_toggle && twitter_toggle) {
        document.getElementById("build_playlist").disabled = false; 
    }
}
```

---

I figured this out by running your code in a browser. There was a syntax error in the dev console that pointed to where the changes were required.

(If you want to use Python-like syntax in your scripts, check out [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/).)

Comment: I didn't even notice the syntax error (silly me)! Thanks for your help!